# Should "python manage.py sql polls" or "python manage.py syncdb" return an error when the models.py code has errors?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models) and when I got to running "[python manage.py sql polls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#activating-models)" it did not print any output. It did not print any errors, nor the expected SQL statements. I assumed that because "exact output will vary depending on the database you are using" that I was ok so I continued on. I then ran "python manage.py syncdb" which did not give any errors. Eventually, I discovered that I had an error because I entered the shell and tried to import "Polls" and Choice" and got an error. I went back and discover a typo in "polls/models.py" and fixed it.

**My question:** Should "python manage.py sql polls" or even "python manage.py syncdb" return an error when the models.py code has errors?

I asked the Django users list yesterday and have not yet received a response so I figured I'd post here. I'm using Django 1.4, Python 2.7.2, Amazon Linux.

Comment: Have you added polls to INSTALLED_APPS? Do you have __init__.py in polls?

Comment: @TomaszWysocki I have, and I do. Those are not the cause of the error, and I already do know what the error is. I just think I could have caught the error earlier if manage.py or syncdb had better error handling. I'm asking if they should, or not. Thanks!